# How to create a multiple watch task with grunt js

Tags: gruntjs

i'm learning how to use grunt. So far i've successfully installed grunt both global and local. I've concatenate and minify one file. My cuestion is: how can i set the task of "watch" for grunt to concatenate two files create another and then minify that file.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat or https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify? These two will help you out significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) which can concatenate and minify files, you do not need to create a multiple task.
Instead, create a task to run the uglify task like below.

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      uglify: {
        files: ['scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify']
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'scripts.js': [
            'scripts/{,*/}*.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });
```